# Connecting Civi to a previous install's database

Tags: database, settings

During my update from Civi 4.2 to 4.7 I let it fill in database information that was not correct it connected to the cms database and not the Civi database from the previous install. Is there a file I can edit to have it connect to the old database?

Answer (score 1):

You should edit the civicrm.settings.php file.  The location of this file depends on your content management system.

Drupal: `sites/default/civicrm.settings.php`

WordPress: `wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php`

Joomla: `administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php`

You may find this related post helpful: [How do I change the CiviCRM Database name](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3503/how-do-i-change-the-civicrm-database-name)